# Redirect test won't pass after click on a link

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, routes, phpunit

I am writing some dummy test with PHPUnit for Symfony, in order to know a little more about functionals tests in PHP.

Here is the problem.
This is my test method :

```
//Redirecting test by clicking on href
public function testRedirect() {
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/redirect');

    $link = $crawler->selectLink('Click me !')->link();
    $client->click($link);

    $crawler2 = $client->followRedirect();
    $this->assertTrue(
            $client->getResponse()->isRedirect()
    );
    $this->assertTrue($crawler2->filter('html:contains("Haha, you\'ve been redirect !")')->count() > 0);
}
```

This is my link :

```
<a href="{{ path('redirect2') }}">Click me !</a>
```

And the message at destination :

```
Haha, you've been redirect !
```

I assume that

```
redirect2
```

is the name of my route.

Test gives me :

```
1) AppBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testRedirect
LogicException: The request was not redirected.
```

So my question is : is href considers as a redirection or not ?

Thanks in advance !
Telest,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you follow the redirect, you're already on the "next" page. Just move the row `$crawler2 = $client->followRedirect();` after the the assert

Comment: Greets,
Thanks for your answer.

I have tried your solution, but I got this message : 

"1) AppBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testRedirect
Failed asserting that false is true."


Does it means that It is not redirected ? 

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it's not redirected. By the way, it's not usual to get a redirection after a click, unless the page you're going on after the click issued a redirect response (not impossible, but unlikely)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. 
What kind of test can I make in order ot test "$client->followRedirect();" ?

Comment: The typical test is after a form submit, since usually after creating a new recordo (or editing an existing one) there is a redirection.